# Multiple votes on one page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple images on the page. Each of the image has `thumb up` and `thumb down` and user is able to vote.
The problem is when user vote on the first image vote is changed but when he click on second image the vote is saved in database but isn't updated and changed on the page. When the page is refreshed the vote counter is updated.

Those are the button and votings for the image

```
$cookie_name = 'vote'.$row['image_id']; // Set up the cookie name           
$value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tc_tuto_yt_voting_system WHERE image_id= ?'); // BDD query, page ID values
$value->bindParam(1, $row['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$value->execute();
$vote = $value->fetch(); 
echo '      

if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) { 
    echo '<div class="vote_up_done oneLine"></div>
          <div class="numberVoted oneLine">'.$vote['positive'].'</div>';
}
else 
{
    echo '<div class="vote_up oneLine" id="voteUp"><a href="#" onclick="vote(\'positive\', \'1\', '.$row['image_id'].'); return false;"></a></div>
          <div class="number oneLine" id="positive">'.$vote['positive'].'</div>';
}                       
if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo '<div class="vote_down_done oneLine"></div>
          <div class="numberVoted oneLine">'.$vote['negative'].'</div>';
}
else 
{ 
    echo '<div class="vote_down oneLine" id="voteDown"><a href="#" onclick="vote(\'negative\', \'1\', '.$row['image_id'].'); return false;"></a></div>
          <div class="number oneLine" id="negative">'.$vote['negative'].'</div>';
}
```

Vote up&down is ajax driven so this is ajax part

```
    function vote(type, value, image_id) {
    var dataFields = {'type': type, 'value': value, 'image_id': image_id}; // We pass the 3 arguments, type: positive or negative ; value=1 ; pageId: here 5
    $.ajax({ // Ajax
        type: "POST",
        url: "ad_vot.php",
        data: dataFields,
        timeout: 3000,
        success: function(dataBack){
            $('#' + type).html(dataBack); // Change the new value in id="positive" or id="negative" DIV
            $('#voteUp').attr('class', 'vote_up_done oneLine'); // Change image by design/vote-up-done.png grey icon
            $('#voteDown').attr('class', 'vote_down_done oneLine'); // Change image by design/vote-down-done.png grey icon
            $('#positive').attr('class', 'numberVoted oneLine'); // Change the number's color by a grey one for the "positive" DIV
            $('#negative').attr('class', 'numberVoted oneLine'); // Change the number's color by a grey one for the "negative" DIV
            $('#message').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Your vote is added!</div>'); // Diplay message with a fadeout
            $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
            });
            },
        error: function() {
            $('#message').text('Vote fail. Please try again.');
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: vote and update

```
    if( $result > 0) {

    $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE tc_tuto_yt_voting_system SET '.$type.' = '.$type.' + 1 WHERE image_id= :image_id');
    $query -> execute(array(
            ":image_id"    => $_POST['image_id']               
    ));
}
else 
{
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $image_id = $_POST['image_id']; 

    $query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO tc_tuto_yt_voting_system (image_id,positive,negative)
                            VALUES (:image_id, :positive, :negative)");   
    $query -> execute(array(
                      ":image_id"           => $_POST['image_id'],
                      ":positive"          => '0',
                      ":negative"          => '0'
    ));     

    $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE tc_tuto_yt_voting_system SET '.$type.' = '.$type.' + 1 WHERE image_id= :image_id');
    $query -> execute(array(
            ":image_id"    => $_POST['image_id']               
    ));    
}

            $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tc_tuto_yt_voting_system WHERE image_id= ?'); // BDD query, page ID values
            $value->bindParam(1, $_POST['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $value->execute();
            $result = $value->fetch();   

    $expire = 24*3600; // 1 day
    setcookie('vote'.$image_id, 'voted', time() + $expire, '/'); // Place a cookie

    echo $result[$type];
```

Comment: From where do you call vote function?

Comment: Wait a sec!! You are manipulating using `id` which has to be unique in `DOM`!! So only one element gets updated on `success` which will be the first element!! I would suggest to use `class` instead of `id` for `upvote` and `downvote` and based on the clicked `row` find the `class` present on that `row` and make changes to it!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao this whole vote system is in loop where images are loaded and you can see I get image_id here on the button `onclick="vote(\'positive\', \'1\', '.$row['image_id'].'); return false;"`

Comment: As Guru states you shouldn't use multiple the same id's. You could do this all by class names, when you simply search for the elements within a container you should put around each image + vote elements

Comment: `Image_id` is not the matter here!! The problem is with your `voteup` and `votedown` ids which gets created multiple times with same `id` because of loop and you cannot manipulate it as expected!! No need of server side code here!! The problem is with your `UI` and `success` function handling after `ajax`

Comment: I understand now where is the problem but I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Make sure you check `$type`'s value before doing `SET '.$type.' = '.$type.' + 1`. (`if (!in_array($type, array("positiove", "negative")) die();`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better answer:

- Don't store the votes in cookie. The user can change it, delete it, and he'll be able to vote again. Create a table in your db, and insert a row when the user votes.
- Don't use `onclick` attribute. Use jQuery's `.on/.bind/.click`.
- As tehy've already explained you, there cannot 2 or more elements on the page with the same id. You need to use classes.
- As I've told you, don't use `SET '.$type.' = '.$type.' + 1` unless you check what's `$type`'s value. `$_POST['type']` can be `positive = 1; DROP TABLE tc_tuto_yt_voting_system;`.

If registering is required for voting:

```
CREATE TABLE user_votes (
  user_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  image_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  vote TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)

$user_votes = $db->prepare("SELECT image_id, vote FROM user_votes WHERE user_id = ?");
$user_votes->bindValue(1, $_SESSION["user_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

If not:

```
CREATE TABLE user_votes (
  user_ip VARBINARY(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  image_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  vote TINYINT(3) NOT NULL
)

$user_votes = $db->prepare("SELECT image_id, vote FROM user_votes WHERE user_id = INET6_ATON(?)");
$user_votes->bindValue(1, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Then display the images, and votes:

```
$user_votes->execute();
$u_votes = [];
while ($vote = $user_votes->fetch())
    $u_votes[$vote->image_id] = $vote->vote;
$images = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM images");
$images->execute();
while ($img = $images->fetch())
{
    $is_voted = isset($u_votes[$img->id]);
    $vote = $is_voted ? ($u_votes[$img->id] ? "down" : "up") : "";
    echo '<img src="'.$img->filename.'" />
          <div class="vote" data-image-id="'.$img->id.'">
              <div class="vote_down'.($vote == "down" ? " voted" : "").'"></div>
              <div class="number positive">'.$img->positive.'</div>
              <div class="vote_up'.($vote == "up" ? " voted" : "").'"></div>
              <div class="number negative">'.$img->negative.'</div>
          </div>';
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".vote .vote_down, .vote .vote_up", function(e)
{
    if ($(e.target).is(".voted"))
        return;
    var that = $(this),
        div = that.parent(),
        type = that.is(".vote_up") ? "positive" : "negative",
        id = div.attr("data-image-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ad_vot.php",
        data: {
            tpye: type,
            image_id: id
        }
        timeout: 3000,
        success: function(dataBack) {
            that.addClass("voted");
            var number = div.find("."+type);
            number.html(parseInt(number.html())+(type == "positive" ? 1 : -1));
            $('#message').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Your vote is added!</div>');
            $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#message').text('Vote failed. Please try again.');
        }
    });
});
```

PHP process:

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM user_votes WHERE image_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
$check->bindValue(1, $_POST["image_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$check->bindValue(2, $_SESSION["user_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

//or
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM user_votes WHERE image_id = ? AND user_ip = INET6_ATON(?)");
$check->bindValue(1, $_POST["image_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$check->bindValue(2, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$check->execute();
if ($check->rowCount())
    die("Already voted.");

$vote = $_POST["type"] == "positive" ? 1 : 0;
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_votes VALUE(?, ?, ?)");
$insert->bindValue(1, $_SESSION["user_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

//or
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_votes VALUE(?, ?, INET6_ATON(?))");
$insert->bindValue(1, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$insert->bindValue(2, $_POST["image_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindValue(3, $vote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->execute();

$row = $vote == 1 ? "positive" : "negative";
$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE images SET ".$row." = ".$row." + 1 WHERE id = ?");
$update->bindValue(1, $POST["image_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I don't want to restrict user vote by IP.. since is not critical function and since with IP restriction I can block entire network of people. Since is not critical function and not everyone know how voting system work (ip, cockie or whatever) i'm good with cookie restriction.

Comment: I will accept your answer BUT is not what I need and accepted only because is good answer and will help to someone else. I don't need entire new voting system.. I just need to can vote for the images on the page..

Comment: I still not recommend you using cookies. However, wherever you store the data, my JS/HTML can help you, that works fine.

Comment: For `JS/HTML` part I will try to implement it. For PHP part I think I will pass for now. I just wanted to ask how and where to put this in my code `if (!in_array($type, array("positiove", "negative")) die();`?

Comment: Before you use it. You can check it in the first line.